# How to call a laravel event or function when socket disconnect event is fired

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, socket.io

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and the thing that I want is to call a custom function from socket event disconnect to update a record in my table `playsessions`.

**Process**:

1. When the user enters to the channel section and I send via AJAX the device information of the user, for example: ip, devide, browser, socket id, etc ... in order to create a record in database.
2. But if the user disconnects, I want to update that record sending the socket id.

Actually, I do the step 1 but, I don't know how to do the second step.

**view Channel.blade.php**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('connect', function() {
    var socket_id = socket.io.engine.id;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ route('play_session.store') }}",
        data: {
            ip: "{{ $play_session_data['ip'] }}",
            device: "{{ $play_session_data['device'] }}",
            platform: "{{ $play_session_data['platform'] }}",
            browser: "{{ $play_session_data['browser'] }}",
            session_id: "{{ $play_session_data['session_id'] }}",
            user_id: "{{ $play_session_data['user_id'] }}",
            channel_id: "{{ $play_session_data['channel_id'] }}",
            socket_id: socket_id
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log('session created');
        }
    });
});
```

**Socket.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(3000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("new client connected " + socket.id);

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('client disconnected');

        // I want to call here a event of laravel or function sending the socket.id to update a record in database 
    });
});
```

Or what is the best way to do something when the user was disconnected from within laravel server.

**Updated**:

I'm using now AJAX in event disconnect but doesn't work:

**view Channel.blade.php**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('connect', function() {
    var socket_id = socket.io.engine.id;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ route('play_session.store') }}",
        data: {
            ip: "{{ $play_session_data['ip'] }}",
            device: "{{ $play_session_data['device'] }}",
            platform: "{{ $play_session_data['platform'] }}",
            browser: "{{ $play_session_data['browser'] }}",
            session_id: "{{ $play_session_data['session_id'] }}",
            user_id: "{{ $play_session_data['user_id'] }}",
            channel_id: "{{ $play_session_data['channel_id'] }}",
            socket_id: socket_id
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log('session created');
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnected', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{ route('play_session.close') }}",
            data: {
                socket_id: socket_id
            },
            success: function() {
                console.log('session closed');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make another Ajax request that sends the id to the server when the user disconnects. Then do the update on the server side. Like you do when a user connects.

Comment: I use this method within view channel but doesn't work. You can see the code updated.

Comment: Why would you rely on an Ajax request if the client disconnects (possibly due to a network failure)? Couldn't you rather use the 'disconnect' event on the server side, to do what you want?

Comment: Yes I want to do that on the server side, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: And the thing that I want to do is update a record with the timestamp in that moment, and know how long the user was connected.

Comment: You can either send an HTTP request from the socket.io server (using something like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) for example), or maybe use Redis pub/sub (but that may be overkill here)

Comment: Yes I'm trying with request library.. thanks

Comment: You have a mistake in your view Channel.blade.php. The event is called `disconnect` and not `disconnected`

Answer (score 0):

You can send an AJAX request with the data you need and fire the event from there.

Comment: I use this method within view channel but doesn't work. You can see the code updated